# SQL : clean way to store all results of a same id in an array?

Tags: sql, arrays

trying to group datas of same id in a table to get less entries.

[image: screenshot]

for exemple, id 1734815 can have {3209782, 3234332}

To do that : we can for exemple make a loop :

```
for ad_id in SELECT DISTINCT(ad_id) in table:
    rows = SELECT duplicate_id FROM table WHERE ad_id = f{ad_id}
    ...
    INSERT INTO new_table(ad_id, _duplicate_id) VALUES (ad_id, {rows});
```

Functional but think is not good : heavy and slow.

Is it possible to do that only with SQL ? Maybe with a sub request ? Thank you

Comment: Why would you want to store the duplicates as comma-separated-values?

Comment: to get less rows, to many duplicates, think is better to store an uniq ID and all values in only 1 row @SalmanA

Comment: What's even better is to normalise your data, so if there's a one-to-many relationship between records, you end up with a separate table mapping the `ad_id` and `duplicate_id` values to each other. If rather, you're wanting to extract this data this way for presentational purposes, then you should look into techniques using `STUFF` and `FOR XML PATH` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44918658/sql-server-join-rows-into-comma-separated-list).