# Some confusion using STUFF/SELECT ... FOR XML to turn rows into columns

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to make a report from a 3rd party DB of rental records. It is driven by a table, aliased X below, that links a lease, a property, a tenant, and one or more units. For instance, FedEx might have a lease called A.2021 that rents two units, 101, 102 in property "br", resulting in two lines in X. fkeys in X link to various informational tables. My query currently returns:

```
propcode    tenname unit    area    months  startdt    enddt
br          FE      101     30876   63      2021-08-01 2026-10-31 
br          FE      102     30876   63      2021-08-01 2026-10-31
```

I would like it to return:

```
propcode    tenname units   area    months  startdt    enddt
br          FE      101,102 30876   63      2021-08-01 2026-10-31
```

I cannot create tables (or #temp or cursors etc.), just SELECT, and it's running pre-2017. As I understand it, [the canonical method](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2914/rolling-up-multiple-rows-into-a-single-row-and-column-for-sql-server-data/) in this case is to use FOR XML PATH and then [STUFF to make it into a comma list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887628/convert-multiple-rows-into-one-with-comma-as-separator).

So I began adapting the examples. First I gather keys in an inner query:

```
hTenant hAmendment  hUnit
45219   1113871     36543
45219   1113871     36544
```

I then use those keys in an outer query where I have the SELECT/FOR XML:

```sql
select p.scode propcode,
       t.slastname tenname,
       a.dcontractarea,
       a.iterm months,
       a.dtstart startdt,
       a.dtend enddt,
       (STUFF((SELECT cast(', ' + ug.scode as varchar(max))
               from unit ug
               where inside.hUnit=ug.hmy
                 and U.HPROPERTY=ug.HPROPERTY
               for xml path('')),1,2,'')) as units
FROM ( select hTenant,
              hAmendment,
              hUnit
       from UNITXREF X
       where dtLeasefrom>'2021-01-01') as inside
      JOIN UNIT U on u.hmy=inside.hUnit
      JOIN PROPERTY P on P.HMY=u.HPROPERTY
      JOIN TENANT T on T.HMYPERSON=inside.hTenant
      JOIN COMMAMENDMENTS A on inside.hAmendment=A.hmy
GROUP BY p.scode,
        t.slastname,
        a.dcontractarea,
        a.iterm,
        a.dtstart,
        a.dtend,
        inside.hUnit,
        u.HPROPERTY
```

I have tried *many* variations on this theme - removing the hproperty (which isn't *really* needed), using the scode instead of the key, etc. All with the same result, multiple rows with one unit per row. I assume the WHERE is failing, [perhaps a missing sub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44918658/sql-server-join-rows-into-comma-separated-list), but I can't understand what is *supposed* to be happening.

What am I missing?

Comment: Some DDL and DML for your tables and sample data would help us here; the only sample data we have is the non-aggregated result set which doesn't help us understand the data or the relationships.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Comment: Unfortunately the tables in question average 50 to 70 columns and the data is confidential. I am not sure what to do.

Comment: @ThomA - a question, what do you mean by "non aggregated"? Perhaps this is the crux of the problem. I think I could solve this if I understood what is supposed to be happening, but none of the pages I found explaining this technique do that, they simply say "do this" with no explanation.  Is the data in the inner supposed to be aggregated? If so, how?

Comment: It seems that you grouped by `inside.hUnit`, but this is the value that you want to aggregate. Try to remove it from the `group by` clause. And probably you must do the same with `u.HPROPERTY`

Comment: "non-aggregated" means it's not aggregated, @MauryMarkowitz .

Comment: *"none of the pages I found explaining this technique"* Explain *what* technique? Using `FOR XML PATH` for string aggregation? Have a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64227488/2029983) where I explain the syntax in more detail than just "do this".

Comment: @RobertoFerraris- removing the group by on hunit cause the SQL to fail as it is not allowed in the SELECT. I did try that.

Answer (score 0):

A **minimal reproducible example** is not provided.

Notable points:

- The CTE simulates a resultset for your multiple tables joins.
- The main `SELECT` has 'p' alias for a parent, 'c' alias for a child
  rows with units.
- We are using `GROUP BY` clause on the p(arent) level to reduce multiple rows to one.
- `WHERE p.propcode = c.propcode` clause simulates join between p(arent)
  and c(hild).

**SQL**

```
;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES
        ('br', 'FE', '101', 30876, 63, '2021-08-01', '2026-10-31'),
        ('br', 'FE', '102', 30876, 63, '2021-08-01', '2026-10-31')
    ) AS t(propcode, tenname, unit, area, months, startdt, enddt)
)
SELECT propcode, tenname 
, (STUFF((SELECT ', ' + c.unit
               from rs AS c -- c(hild)
               where p.propcode = c.propcode
                 and p.tenname = c.tenname
                 and p.area = c.area
                 and p.months = c.months
                 and p.startdt = c.startdt
                 and p.enddt = c.enddt
               for xml path('')),1,2,'')) as units
, area, months, startdt, enddt
FROM rs AS p    -- p(arent)
GROUP BY propcode, tenname, area, months, startdt, enddt;
```

**Output**

| propcode | tenname | units | area | months | startdt | enddt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| br | FE | 101, 102 | 30876 | 63 | 2021-08-01 | 2026-10-31 |